# Difference between it and so

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

What is the difference between

> I think it would be wise to do so.

and

> I think it would be wise to do it.

Do 'so' and 'it' have the same grammatical category?

Comment: The sentences appear to be equivalent in meaning, but I would prefer “so” over “it”. In this case, “so” is an adverb, whereas “it” is a pronoun. I'm not sure what you meant by “grammatical category”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[to do so](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so) is a very specific idiom meaning **to act in the way mentioned**, this could be a single action, but it is more likely to involve some long term plan. It is also more formal, and is therefore appropriate when giving professional advice.

> Are you going to stop smoking? I think it would be wise to do so

**to do it**, on the other hand, refers more to a single action.

> There is a parachute jump next week: do you want to do it?

In most situations, either would be appropriate.

Comment: To me, "so" as an adverb points to the action ("stop" in your example), while "it" as a pronoun points to the linked topic ("parachute drop" in your example). Then, "Are you going to stop smoking? I think it would be wise to *stop*." and "There is a parachute jump next week: do you want to do *the parachute jump*"?

Comment: @user3169: "I heard that you were planning to get married. Are you really doing to do it?" ... **get married** is an action, but it would sound strange to say "do so".

Comment: Hmm... I see no problem with "Are you planning to get married? I think it would be wise to do so, since you aren't getting any younger." *planning* is the action here. But I think "The wedding is next week. Are you sure you want to do it?" is fine. In your example, "it" refers to marriage, not the planning activity.